# JHipster - Yarn Build failure

Tags: jhipster, yarnpkg

Using Jhipster v5.0.1 and Angular v6.0.0

**Goal**

I want to do a yarn build so that my scss file is taken into account but it fails:

**In the terminal :**

```
C:\Users\clari\Documents\ManuelaTechValley\crafrontmanu>yarn build
yarn run v1.5.1
$ yarn run webpack:prod
$ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
$ rimraf target/{aot,www}
'rimraf' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c rimraf target/{aot,www}
Directory: C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**In the yarn-error :**

```
Trace: 
  Error: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  Arguments: /d /s /c yarn run webpack:prod
  Directory: C:\Users\clari\Documents\Manuela\crafrontmanu
  Output:

      at ProcessTermError.MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:186:110)
      at new ProcessTermError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:226:113)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:30281:17)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I found this issue. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5481
I wonder if this is my problem, the reason why it doesn't find some dependencies for building. I have the version 1.5.1 but if I try to update, my terminal answer already up-to-date...

**EDIT 2 :**

I suppressed all node-modules and did a yarn install again. The rimraf prob is not there anymore. But still, it doesn't work.

```
    Trace: 
  Error: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  Arguments: /d /s /c yarn run webpack:prod
  Directory: C:\Users\clari\Documents\Manuela\crafrontmanu
  Output: ".

  at ProcessTermError.MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:186:110)
  at new ProcessTermError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:226:113)
  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:30281:17)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)


C:\Users\clari\Documents\Manuela\crafrontmanu>yarn build
yarn run v1.5.1
$ yarn run webpack:prod
$ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
$ rimraf target/{aot,www}
$ yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
$ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
(node:12788) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Hash: 83726fc3895998baed92
Version: webpack 4.8.0
Time: 8976ms
Built at: 2018-10-02 15:01:08
 7 assets
Entrypoint polyfills = app/polyfills.83726fc3895998baed92.bundle.js
Entrypoint global = app/global.83726fc3895998baed92.bundle.js content/global.83726fc3895998baed92.css
Entrypoint main = app/main.83726fc3895998baed92.bundle.js
[0] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 0 bytes {0} [built]
    factory:4418ms building:4087ms = 8505ms
[1] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {2} [built]
    factory:4418ms building:4072ms = 8490ms
[5] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 2.17 KiB [built]
    [6] -> factory:625ms building:728ms = 1353ms
[6] ./src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css 41 bytes [built]
    + 3 hidden modules


error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 2
Command: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
Directory: C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c yarn run webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile
Directory: C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
Directory: C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c yarn run webpack:prod
Directory: C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\clari\\Documents\\Manuela\\crafrontmanu\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**EDIT 3 :**

Try to launch prod Build using mvnw Pprod. The build also fails.

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:55 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-02T16:29:48+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) on project crafrontmanu: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error:
 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

**EDIT 4 :**

There were errors that I fixed. It was not preventing yarn start that's why I didn't pay attention to it before but it prevented yarn build apparently. Problem solved then. Thks for your time.

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: Any reason why you can't upgrade jhipster in your project?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it... without erasing all the changes I have already made..

Comment: Commit everything and then run `jhipster upgrade`, see doc https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: I did the upgrade and now the yarn start doesn't work either... and I cannot open my app anymore..

Comment: Please be precise in what does not work and update your question. Any problem you have is not a fatal issue as you can still rollback to previous version using git.

Comment: @Manuela, What do you mean by ' preventing yarn start' and how did you fix it ?

Comment: @Farouk, as I said in my EDIT 4, there were some syntax error in my code. Sometimes, despite syntax error, yarn start still works. However, when you do yarn build, it doesn't work anymore. I just fixed my syntax errors and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like rimraf was not installed locally in your project's `node_modules`, so maybe there was an error during the yarn install phase that you did not notice.

Try deleting `node_modules` folder in your project and then run `yarn install`and check that rimraf is present in your `node_modules` folder. If there was no error and it's missing, check that rimraf is declared as a dev dependency in your project's `package.json`

Comment: When I look into package.json, the dev dependency is here:  "rimraf": "2.6.1". The yarn install doesn't pop up an error... (yarn istall v1.5.1 already up to date). And rimraf is in the node_modules.

Comment: This is strange, a quick workaround could be to install it globally with `yarn global add rimraf`

Comment: even after yarn global add rimraf, I get the same trace in yar-error, and in the console I get both exit code 2 and exit code 1 but it doesn't say that it does not find rimraf...

Comment: Are you able to run rimraf manually.from command prompt? Maybe there's a problem with your PATH env variable or you made a mix of npm and yarn in your global installations. Have you tested a prod build because it does not use your node env on your PC so it makes a difference.

Comment: rimraf seems ok now after deleting and installing node_modules ok... I have other errors in the edit above.

Comment: what do you mean for the prod build, please?

Comment: I mean using the prod profile: `mvnw -Pprod`   see https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181161/discussion-between-gael-marziou-and-manuela-codingpadawan).